# Excel - Condensing a table, omitting columns/rows with only blank cells

Tags: excel

I am setting up a template workbook that has a summary sheet which essentially summarises all of the data from the rest of the workbook.

One of the results is reported as a large table which is only partially populated, as shown below:

```
Peptide Mod 1   Mod 2   Mod 3   Mod 4
1:T1    20.1%           
1:T3                
1:T4                
1:T8            1.0%
1:T8-9              
1:T9                
1:T19               
1:T20               
1:T21-22        5.7%            6.0%
```

This is not very clear (this is only a small example, the actual data set is a lot larger) and I would like to be able to automatically remove all of the blanks.

Basically I would like a formula that can condense this as shown below:

```
Peptide Mod 1   Mod 2   Mod 4
1:T1    20.1%       
1:T8            1.0%
1:T21-22        5.7%    6.0%
```

I've been trying to think how I might do it with VLOOKUP and IF statements but can't really think how I would get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks, 
Henry

Comment: I think you only have two options: 1) Use VBA, or if you don't want to use VBA, 2) Make a helper column which is used to calculate if the row is blank and then use a filter to filter out those rows that are blank. Which option do you prefer?

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of the helper column *facepalm*, I was trying to be too complicated. Thanks very much, I can manage a helper columns and filter :)